# Выгрузка заказов с сайта Bitrix, SQL ошибка

Tags: php, sql, битрикс, 1с

Вообщем ситуация, нужно сделать интеграцию заказов c 1C на сайте битрикс)
Перед тем как давать ссылку на обмен, решил пройтись по пунктам, посмотреть придет ли XML с заказами:

1. http://<сайт>/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange.php?type=sale&mode=checkauth
   получил токен, добавил в ссылку
2. http://<сайт>/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange.php?type=sale&mode=init&токен&version=2.08
3. http://<сайт>/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange.php?type=sale&mode=query&токен

В итоге ошибка:

```css
[Bitrix\Main\DB\SqlQueryException] 
Mysql query error: (1054) Unknown column 'sale_exchange_internals_exchange_log.PROVIDER' in 'where clause' (400)
SELECT 
    MAX(`sale_exchange_internals_exchange_log`.`DATE_INSERT`) AS `MAX_DATE_INSERT`
FROM `b_sale_exchange_log` `sale_exchange_internals_exchange_log` 

WHERE `sale_exchange_internals_exchange_log`.`DIRECTION` = 'E'
AND `sale_exchange_internals_exchange_log`.`PROVIDER` = 'onec'
```

Как это можно исправить?
В комментарии пользователь SwaD помог, спасибо тебе, навыков пока у меня 0)
У кого будет подобная ошибка надо создать колонку PROVIDER  в таблице  b_sale_exchange_log

Comment: Так у вас в ошибке же все написано... **sale_exchange_internals_exchange_log.PROVIDER** нет такого поля в таблице

Comment: Да, создал колонку PROVIDER в таблице  b_sale_exchange_log все заработало, спасибо!)

Comment: Вы вообще понимаете, что вы делаете и зачем? Ну добавите вы поле и какой результат вы получите?(Подскажу - пусто, т.к. созданное поле пустое). Сверяйте поля в таблице с полями из вашего запроса. и вот это **sale_exchange_internals_exchange_log** алиас таблицы, а поле **PROVIDER**

Comment: Нашел БД с рабочем модулем обмена, в таблице  b_sale_exchange_log добавлена колонка PROVIDER, в моей не было, вообщем в этом проблема, ошибка исчезла

Answer (score 1):

У вас падает ошибка, что нет колонки PROVIDER в таблице `b_sale_exchange_log`.

То, что вы её создали руками, конечно, замечательно, но мыслить нужно немного шире! Похоже, что у вас криво прошло обновление битрикса.

Вы бы, на всякий случай, проверили целостность таблиц базы данных в целом:

Настройки > Инструменты > Диагностика > Проверка БД

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=35&LESSON_ID=2032

Answer (score 0):

В комментарии пользователь SwaD помог, спасибо тебе. У кого будет подобная ошибка надо создать колонку PROVIDER в таблице b_sale_exchange_log